# iOS Make Custom Keyboard Generate Standard Key Strokes For UITextField

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

OK I have looked and looked and I think I am missing something about custom keyboards and inserting text into a `UITextField`.  Like many people I am creating a `UIView` custom keyboard with my own set of key caps on custom `UIButtons`.  I then assign this view to the UITextField's `inputView` and then my keyboard pops up when that text field becomes the first responder.  Internal to the keyboard I capture button actions and translate them to what would be keystrokes.

But from here I am puzzled about how to best send my keystrokes to the text field.  I have seen plenty of examples like [iOS Custom Keyboard Updating Text Field In Parent View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140770/ios-custom-keyboard-updating-text-field-in-parent-view) and [Return Inputs To UITextfield With Custom Inputview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224757/return-inputs-to-uitextfield-with-custom-inputview) and [How To Push Key Value Into UITextView From Custom Keyboard In iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788937/how-to-push-key-value-into-uitextview-from-custom-keyboard-in-ios) where the solution seems to be to embed a pointer to the target `UITextField` inside the custom view.

This does not seem right to me, as for multiple `UITextFields` either I have to have to manually change references on a single custom keyboard  whenever a new text field becomes the first responder, or I have to carry around a matching  custom keyboard for each text field I want to support.

It seems to me that a keyboard should just translate touches into tokens and send those tokens up the line to be interpreted by whoever receives them (first responder?).  [iPad For iPhone Developers 101 Custom Input View Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1063/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-custom-input-view-tutorial) seems to do this, but creates a custom protocol to do so.  I imagine (actually a SWAG - Scientific Wild Arsed Guess) that the standard iOS keyboards operate like that, but use a specific protocol to pass along the keystrokes.  So what I want to be able to do is to manually generate the same chain of events/messages that the standard keyboard does.

So how can I do this?  Or can I even do this with public APIs?  Or is the operation of the standard keyboards bound too tightly to the UITextField?

Comment: I know that this question is old, but I created a complete, working, open source example of just how to do this called Numberpad, and put it on [Github](https://github.com/lnafziger/Numberpad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very open ended question. Really, it's up to you to pick what you want. [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) states this:

> The subviews of an input view and input accessory view can be anything you want. If they are buttons or other controls, you need to specify targets and actions for each control and implement the associated action methods to perform data input or manipulation.

You could also make a UITextField subclass and explicitly implement the getter for `inputView` to return a pointer to your custom keyboard view class. In this getter you can set up a UIControl-like target/action system as you suggest earlier. Doing it this way removes the need to set the custom keyboard from the outside--it's all handled internally. It also puts that code into only one place.

Once the custom text field resigns first responder, you can strip the text field's pointer out of the keyboard.

Comment: In a sense I am asking for exactly what the Apple Docs state - methods to implement data input.  In this case I want those methods to emulate the standard ones so that I can exchange my keyboard for the apple one with minimal code changes (ie setting or not setting inputView only).  Subclassing UITextField is on my list for other reasons (and is my fallback in this case too), but I still consider shuffling the UITextField pointers in a subclass to be manual manipulation and it offends me to do so in a message passing environment that is already capable of doing what I want.

Comment: I think you're making the custom keyboard functionality into something it's not. A custom keyboard is just a view. It's not some special subclass of Apple's private keyboard framework (a large and complicated thing) that gives you hooks into their system. Imagine if you made a custom keyboard where the user doesn't press buttons to enter text, but draws pictures instead. How could Apple's internal key forwarding code possibly send this data to the text field?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to iOS, so please forgive me if what I'm saying makes no sense (and be kind enough to correct me, please). :D

Isn't there a way for your custom keyboard to go through all the UITextFields in the main UIView looking for the FistResponder and send its messages to that FirstResponder? I mean, UIView has a subviews property where you could look for UITextFields and find the FirstResponder using the [UITextField isFirstResponder] property. Then, could you use that object?

Again, I'm sorry if this makes no sense, but I'm also very interested in this thread and wanted to contribute a little.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I am not sure that it is any better than what I am doing.  I already have to explicitly assign a concrete instance of a custom keyboard to a specific text field.  So to me it is a bit Rube Goldberg to have the keyboard itself search through view stack in order to find the first responder.  To me what is missing is giving the keyboard explicit knowledge of the text field it is bound to.